# Image upload using jbimages plugin for TinyMCE not working

Tags: tinymce, justboil.me

I am initializing tinymce editor along with the `jbimages` plugin.  My configuration is as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea#abstract",
   plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
],
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link  jbimages",
relative_urls:false
```

});

When I try to upload an image all its showing "The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable."
I have given 777 to all the folders in my project and to the project itself.

Not sure how to find the path where it is uploading image.

Comment: As you are loading the `jbimages` plugin this is really a question tied to that plugin ... you should make that more obvious in your question title and details.

Comment: Thank you Michael. The upload path for image in jbimages config was not mentioned.